# Does prior refer to the one which is exactly one place earlier, or any one which is before the current one?

Tags: meaning, numbers, latin

https://www.etymonline.com/word/prior says

> prior (adj.)
>
> "earlier; preceding, as in order of time," 1714, from Latin prior
> "former, previous, first;" figuratively "superior, better;" as a noun
> "forefather; superior rank;" comparative of Old Latin pri "before"
> (from PIE *prai-, *prei-, from root *per- (1) "forward," hence "in
> front of, before, first"). Also used adverbially (with to), by 1706.

Suppose there is a sequence of things.

- In English, does prior mean the one which is exactly one place earlier from the current one, or any one that is before the current one?

Comment: I'ved edited to remove the question about the [latin.se]

Comment: When you are not sure of the meaning of a word, you should first look it up in a dictionary. Some dictionaries also give the etymology. But the answer to both your qu4esitons is no, it's not that specific. Just means at some time before.

Comment: You can find [many examples of "all prior" in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all+prior%22), which should strongly hint that *prior* can refer to any one before the current one.

Comment: Etymonline is great for etymology, but it's not a proper dictionary. As @BillyKerr suggests, you should look in an actual dictionary, which will almost certainly answer your question. If it doesn't, then describe your research in the question and explain why it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Etymonline tells you about etymology.  To find the current meaning of a word, you should use a [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/prior)

> existing or happening before something else:
> The course requires no prior knowledge of Spanish.

It doesn't mean "one place before" - but "at some time before (a time or event)